# Unable to download content version in community

Tags: community, force.com, force.com-sites

User that logged in customer community is not able to download content version files through this link https:////sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/
User license is 'customer portal login user'
Srm content user checkbox is flagged. Gets this error: 
'URL is not found'
Any ideas?

Comment: what's the exact url that you're using? Obviously the thing above is not valid, as it doesn't contain a content version id and also there is no domain name at the beginning..